# Getting all documentIDs from a collection in Cloud Firestore with javascript web API

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to get all document IDs in one shot (as a single read) from a collection (or subcollection) with Cloud Firestore javascript web library? I don't want to read their content, I only need the id-s. As far as I could monitor in Chrome `var docs = (await firebase.firestore().collection("collection-path").get()).docs.map(x => x.id)` will retrieve the content inclusive. As I am talking about a large collection it takes quite a while, and this is not an option even if it would count a single read operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such API in the provided client libraries.  You have to query for all the documents and read them, even if you just want their IDs.

Comment: And how does this count?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How many read operations are counted? One in total or one fir each document touched - or something inbetween?

Comment: Any time a document appears in a query result, it is one document read, assuming that it did not come from the client's local cache.

Comment: Well, this certainly is a missing feature - if not something worse. But it looks to be the fact today :(